# Is it possible to print out a string corresponding to the counter of a loop

Tags: c++, string

I tried creating a loop and using the append function.
example:

```
string a = "hey";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << a << endl;
    a += a;
}
```

For example, if I wanted to print out

```
heyheyhey
heyhey
hey
```

then this method would fail.

BUT if I wanted to print out

```
hey
heyday
heyheyhey
```

then this method would work; since the append function adds the string to the end as per the number of loop iterations. Is it possible to solve this solution as per the way I am trying? Or is there a way to recursively swap the bottom solution to attain the top solution? I've been learning strings and I was hoping that I could solve this problem using string functions.

Comment: You can use function like `printCount(string text, int count)
{
    for(int now = 0; now < count; now++)
        printf(text);
}` 
and then use it in your loop like `for(int now = 1; now < 4; now++) printCount("hey", now)`

Comment: @Mikhail : That is an answer not a comment - post an answer.

Comment: The code presented did not produce the output you suggest;  I have fixed it so that it does.

Comment: Is it your intent to construct a string with the repeats or simply generate the output?  The latter is trivial, and is what the answer you have accepted does, but that is not what you are doing or asking in your question, where you are constructing a repeated string object for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods for this:

1. Start with large string, erase pieces
2. Use nested loop

With the large string, you will need to start with "heyheyhey" and print the string then erase a "hey" in each loop.  It's the opposite of concatenation.

The other method is to use nested loops:

```
for (unsigned int line = 0; line < 3; ++line)
{
  for (unsigned int copies_per_line = 0; copies_per_line < (3 - line); ++copies_per_line)
  {
    cout << "hey";
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: *At least* two, you could use recursion.

Comment: This solution produces the correct output, but does not construct a repeated string object as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just stick your `cout` in a `for` loop.  Just be careful on how you handle the conditional and increment.

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "hey";
for(int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
{
    for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        cout << a;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: It produces the correct console output, but in the question, a string `a` is constructed with the repeats, which i believe is the aim..

Answer (score 0):

you can create aditional function that wiil print text X times:

```
void printCount(string text, int count)
{
    for(int now = 0; now < count; now++)
        printf(text);
}
```

Then you can create main loop that wiil display your text:

```
for(int now = 0; now < 3; now++)
    printCount("hey", now + 1);
```

There now + 1 mean that in cycle 0 we need to print 1 msg, in cycle 1 - 2 and more

For your situation:

```
for(int now = 3; now > 0; now--)
    printCount("hey", now);
```

EDIT:
You can use cout also:

```
void printCount(string text, int count)
{
    for(int now = 0; now < count; now++)
        cout << text;
    cout << endln;
}
```

Comment: Or `for (int now = 3; now > 0; now--) printCount("hey", now);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes. It is very easy to use =)

Comment: I assume from the question that the aim is to construct a string containing the repeats rather then simply repeating the output to the console.

Answer (score 0):

By the way your method fails even for the second case. It will not print

```
hey
heyday
heyheyhey
```

but

```
hey
heyhey
heyheyheyhey
```

as the string always doubles in each iteration.

As other answers state, you can just simply use an additional inner loop.

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer.  The point has already been commented on and the question fixed before your post; which is why you should *only* answer the question in an answer rather then comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately isn't as trivial as it seems. I see two potential solution: store the output in the loop the first time and print on a second loop, or create `a` the first time and create the output in a second loop. Either way, I can't see how to do this in a single loop.

Since copying strings into arrays is a bit annoying, here's the second solution.

```
string a = "hey";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  a += a;

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  int copyLength = (3 - j) * "hey".length();
  cout << a.substr(0, copyLength) << endl;
}
```

**Note:** I would strongly consider making `3` a `const` or at least a variable here. All instances of `3` in the above code should be changed together.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what arbitrary restrictions you are placing on yourself, but the output can be trivially obtained in many ways.  Here is a recursive solution:

```
std::string repeat(std::string str, int rpt)
{
    return (rpt > 1) ? str + repeat(str, rpt - 1) : str; 
}

int main()
{

    for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
    {
        std::string a = repeat( "hey", i);
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```